# Refactoring JavaScript function results

Tags: javascript, leaflet, refactoring

I'm working on a project using Leaflet's Mapping API. Right now, I'm cleaning up my code and there's one section I feel could be made better.

I have it set when the location is found, the location is checked both in accuracy and in bounds:

```
function checkLocation(position)
{
    if(position.accuracy > 100)
    {
        return 4;
    }
    else if((position.latlng.lat <= **bound** || position.latlng.lat >= **bound**) || (position.latlng.lng >= **bound** || position.latlng.lng <= **bound**))
    {
        return 5;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, if the accuracy is too low, I throw an error with error code 4. If the coordinates are outside of where I want them to be, I throw an error with error code 5 (These are to correspond to Leaflet's builtin error codes 1-3 so I can switch on them later). I return 0 just to say there wasn't an error.

This function is called by the locationFound event, which has the following code:

```
var temp = checkLocation(position);
if(temp != 0)
{
    // Handle error code
    return;
}
```

This also works, but I'm not fond of how this looks. What I want is for this bit to only take like two to three lines, preferably without an if statement. I originally had the code for checkLocation in this section, but I thought having it on its own would make for cleaner and more reader-friendly code.

My question is is there any way to improve this bit? I looked into lambda expressions but didn't think it fit and I tried using a Promise, but at that point, I was losing lines trying to cut down on lines. I don't want to code golf the code, but I'm still pretty new to JavaScript and I don't know if there's any way to simplify this while still looking professional. I'm also up for changing the checkLocation function if it means improving the code.

Comment: The last code block could be `if (checkLocation(position)) return;`

Comment: For readability I would change the function name to `locationError()`, then you can have the easily understood: `if  (locationError(position)) { } `

Comment: I should add that there is a function called locationError that is called where I commented "// Handle error code" which is the switch statement on the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you refactor to this:

```
function invalidAccuracy(position) {
    return position.accuracy > 100; 
}

function outOfBounds(position) {
    return (position.latlng.lat <= **bound** || position.latlng.lat >= **bound**) || (position.latlng.lng >= **bound** || position.latlng.lng <= **bound**);
}
```

You can handle it like this:

```
function checkLocation(position) {
    if(invalidAccuracy(position)) 
        return 4;

    if(outOfBounds(position)) 
        return 5;

    return 0;
}
```

You can (if you want) put it in 1 line then:

```
return invalidAccuracy(position) ? 4:
       outOfBounds(position) ? 5 :
       0;
```